# Run .net code in a separate process

Tags: .net, concurrency, process

In an impersonation scenario related to Sharepoint I need to execute some code in a separate process (the process will run in the context of a certain user). I do not want to launch a separate application, basically I want to do a "run as" on just a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Process.Start method has an overload to start the process provided you have the appropriate user, password and domain.

What you want to do is create a ProcessStartInfo object and specify the proper UserName and Password when starting the process. So you can do something like this:

```
Dim psiNewProcess As New ProcessStartInfo("Notepad.exe")

psiNewProcess.UserName = "MyUserName"
psiNewProcess.Password = "MyPassword"

Process.Start(psiNewProcess)
```

Oh, Process is in the System.Diagnostics namespace if it isn't already imported for your project.

EDIT: Quick sidenote, the password field is actually a SecureString type object, so MSDN suggests filling the value in this way:

```
Dim instance As ProcessStartInfo
Dim value As SecureString

value = instance.Password

instance.Password = value
```

Comment: I do not want to launch a new application. Is it possible to use ProcessStartInfo to run a piece of code from the application in which I create the new process?

Comment: No, it's not possible to use ProcessStartInfo to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this myself but [this seems](http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/Permalink,guid,36633846-2eca-40fe-9957-2859d8a244dc.aspx) to do the trick.

If you are fine with the impersonated method blocking until it finishes it should work.
So your code would be something like:

```
...
WrapperImpersonationContext context = new WrapperImpersonationContext(domain, username, password);
context.Enter();

Results res = MyImpersonatedMethod(data);

context.Leave();
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But it says Permalink in the url! :)

Comment: Guess this is it: http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/CommentView,guid,36633846-2eca-40fe-9957-2859d8a244dc.aspx
Googling WrapperImpersonationContext returns some results.

Comment: And 3 years later... http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2006/07/windowsimpersonationcontext-made-easy/

Answer (score 1):

"Execute code in a separate process" = "launch a separate application" though.

I mean, you could launch a single process and then make requests to it to run the particular method... but it's not clear whether that's what you want.

Comment: Could you point to where can find more info on this subject, maybe an example. This is what I want to do.

Comment: Basically you'd need to start a new process (once) and communicate over a named pipe (or whatever). If you're using a recent version of .NET, WCF may be the best option - so pick up a WCF book or tutorial.